# I'm facing the migration issue magento 1.9.3.9 to magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

There are showing some errors in migration How we can resolve it. anyone can resolve this issue ??

```
E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2>php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of Iterator: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php on line 35 in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php(11): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'E:\\xampp81\\htdo...', 35)
#1 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(578): include('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#2 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#3 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\Document\Collection.php(11): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Migration\\Resou...')
#4 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(578): include('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#5 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#6 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Migration\\Resou...')
#7 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\GetParameterClassTrait.php(34): ReflectionClass->__construct('Migration\\Resou...')
#8 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(42): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getParameterClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Migration\\Resou...')
#10 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Migration\\Resou...')
#11 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Resou...')
#12 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Resou...')
#13 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\Resou...', NULL, 'source', 'Migration\\App\\S...')
#14 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#15 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#16 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#17 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\App\\S...')
#18 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\App\\S...')
#19 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\App\\S...', NULL, 'setupDeltaLog', 'Migration\\Mode\\...')
#20 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#21 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#22 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#23 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Mode\\...')
#24 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Mode\\...')
#25 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\Mode\\...', NULL, 'dataMode', 'Migration\\Conso...')
#26 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#27 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#28 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#29 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Conso...')
#30 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Console\CommandList.php(52): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Conso...')
#31 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(226): Migration\Console\CommandList->getCommands()
#32 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(159): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getVendorCommands(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager))
#33 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(134): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands()
#34 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1286): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands()
#35 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(631): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init()
#36 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(237): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('migrate:setting...')
#37 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#40 {main} in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php on line 11

Fatal error: During inheritance of Iterator: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php on line 35 in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php(11): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'E:\\xampp81\\htdo...', 35)
#1 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(578): include('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#2 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#3 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\Document\Collection.php(11): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Migration\\Resou...')
#4 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(578): include('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#5 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(432): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::Composer\Autoload\{closure}('E:\\xampp81\\htdo...')
#6 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Migration\\Resou...')
#7 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\GetParameterClassTrait.php(34): ReflectionClass->__construct('Migration\\Resou...')
#8 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(42): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getParameterClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#9 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Migration\\Resou...')
#10 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Migration\\Resou...')
#11 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Resou...')
#12 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Resou...')
#13 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\Resou...', NULL, 'source', 'Migration\\App\\S...')
#14 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#15 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#16 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\App\\S...', Array, Array)
#17 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\App\\S...')
#18 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\App\\S...')
#19 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\App\\S...', NULL, 'setupDeltaLog', 'Migration\\Mode\\...')
#20 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#21 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#22 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\Mode\\...', Array, Array)
#23 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Mode\\...')
#24 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Mode\\...')
#25 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Migration\\Mode\\...', NULL, 'dataMode', 'Migration\\Conso...')
#26 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#27 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#28 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Migration\\Conso...', Array, Array)
#29 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Migration\\Conso...')
#30 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Console\CommandList.php(52): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Migration\\Conso...')
#31 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(226): Migration\Console\CommandList->getCommands()
#32 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(159): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getVendorCommands(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager))
#33 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(134): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getApplicationCommands()
#34 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1286): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->getDefaultCommands()
#35 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(631): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->init()
#36 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(237): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find('migrate:setting...')
#37 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\bin\magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#40 {main} in E:\xampp81\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Migration tools is not compatible with PHP 8

Downgrade PHP to 7.4 and it should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please install Data Migration Tool from that branch or use PHP 7.4 as a workaround during migration.

- This issue was Fixed in [2.4-develop](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/tree/2.4-develop)

Comment: Thanks Let me check